# Configuring IPv4 interaction on an IPv6-only server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ipv6, centos-7

I have an `IPv6-only` virtual server. I can connect to it via SSH or use `ping6`, but I can't work with IPv4. For example, get a file via `wget` (Network is unreachable). I have software that cannot be installed because of this, as far as I know it can work on an IPv6-only server in its installed form.

Is it possible to return the ability to interact with IPv4 without additional costs (for example, buying an IPv4 address)?

*This is my first experience of interacting with IPv6 and trying to configure the network.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the network operator (i.e. your hosting provider) offers it – the same as getting IPv6 on a v4-only server.

For example, your host *might* offer an outbound-only NATed IPv4 service (without a dedicated IPv4 address – just like CGNAT at home), or they *might* offer NAT64 (similar but makes the IPv4 "world" look like it's IPv6 on your side), or at least an HTTP proxy to use for outbound connections.

If the network operator doesn't offer any alternative ways to access the IPv4 internet, then your last option is to tunnel it through elsewhere – practically the same way as people bring external IPv6 to a v4-only site. You could use a commercial VPN service here (as long as its servers are reachable via IPv6), or you could set up your own tunnel through another nearby dual-stack server that you already own.